# loop to check if elements exist in jquery/js

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, exists

so, I have an HTML file with some lets call them boxes. Each box has an ID: CC1, CC2, etc. I'm looking todo some kind of loop where I type CC and add `i` to the end, so it should ask if CC+`i` exists through .length

My goal here is to stop on the highest existing `CCi`. This is my try:

```
for (i=1; $('#cc'+i).length = 0; i++ ){
    console.log('#cc'+i)
}
```

Thank you!

```js
    var i
    for (i=1; $('#cc'+i).length = 0; i++ ){
        console.log('#cc'+i)
    }
```

```css
.container{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'container' id = 'cc1'>
<div class = 'container' id = 'cc1'>
```

(sorry, my first time using snippet)

Comment: What is the issues you are facing at this moment? Can you include a snippet of [mcve] by [edit]ing your question?

Comment: I think it's done

Comment: Note that a single `=` is going to try and set `length` to 0. You likely want `=== 0`.

Comment: Also it looks like you have 2 `div` elements with the same `id` attribute `cc1`... That's probably a typo - 2 html elements should never have the same `id`

Comment: that was my bad while doing the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to do a small fix to your `for-loop`, try this:

```
for (var i = 1; $('#cc' + i).length !== 0; i++){
    console.log('#cc' + i)
}
```

This will start from `#cc1`, and loop until `#cc<number>` doesn't exist, printing all of the `#cc<number>` values that *do* exist.

Here's why your loop is a bit off:

The middle condition of your `for-loop` should be checking to make sure the `#cc<number>` element DOES exist, as this is the condition for the loop to continue. When you have `$('#cc'+i).length == 0`, (adding a 2nd equals sign to fix the formatting), this is basically saying "continue the loop if the element *doesn't* exist", which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
var i = 0;
while($('#cc'+i).length > 1){i++}
console.log('cc'+i);
```

The console.log will return the highest cc

Comment: I modified this to 
    var i = 1;
    while($('#cc'+i).length > 0){i++}
        console.log('#cc'+i)

and I think it does what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's better to set the value to 1 i forgot, Your welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it does exactly what you need, but maybe you can build on that!

I'm just checking the length of all elements starting with cc.

The problem in your code is that your loop have no ending here. You're looping until i = 0, wich will never happen

```js
$count = $('div[id^="cc"]').length;
console.log($count);
```

```css
div{
background-color:blue;
margin:1rem;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cc1">
1
</div>
<div id="cc2">
2
</div>
<div id="cc3">
3
</div>
<div id="cc4">
4
</div>
<div id="cc5">
5
</div>
<div id="cc6">
6
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did a bit more please? Also, on my example, it should stop once it finds one that doesn't exist (or that's what I meant it to do)